# 3 part distributed right side advertisment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for information.
Does someone ever heard about this kinda add?

I'm trying programming an add which opening itself when you click on it, but I'm stuck.

I found a solution if you wanna an opening style add like 2 distributed parts but not for 3 or more side, so if it's possible, so someone can help me find out how can I solve this problem? 
This is the html file

I tried the 3rd "distribution" but that stucked under the 2nd so I deleted that part of the code.

```css
.cards {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.card-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 900;
  margin: auto auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card:hover .face {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.inner-left {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-10deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.inner-left>img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.inner-right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.card:hover .front,
.card:hover .inner-left {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-15deg);
}

.card-toggle:checked+.card .front,
.card-toggle:checked+.card .inner-left {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card-toggle:checked+.card .inner-right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='cards'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="card-toggle" class="card-toggle" value="selected">
  <label class='card' for="card-toggle">
      <div class='front face'>
       Font view of the advertisement.
      </div>
    
      <div class="inner-left face">
       <img class="inner-left" width=300px height="600px" src='http://picanimal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cats-cat-play-hide-cute-pictures-hd-1366x768.jpg' />
      </div>
    
      <div class="inner-right face">
       <img class="inner-left" width=300px height="600px" src='http://picanimal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cats-cat-play-hide-cute-pictures-hd-1366x768.jpg' />
      </div>
     </label>
</div>
```

Comment: if you're trying to code something, post the code here and describe your problem in detail and maybe we can help you fix it. Without code we're just generalising and guessing, which probably will not help you. Also your description is not very clear. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, you right, I forgotten about that.

The add had 2 image. One for the "closed" add and 1 for if you click on this add, after you clicked on this add, it's open itself and it's going to be one bigger add. The first image is about W:300px H:600px, the second is W: 900px H:600px an I imagined this can "slide".

Comment: thanks. I've edited it into a runnable snippet to make it easier to visualise. But you still haven't clarified your description. I can see some code, and I can see that it probably isn't what you want, but I haven't got a clear enough idea of what you _do_ want.

Comment: Right so,

The whole advertisement start as an 300px width and 600px heigh image, I imagined this image advertisement be on the right side on my webpage, but if you click on this it's going to be a 900px width 600px height advertisement and it has another image file not that one which used in the "closed" one, and the problem is that, I can't get how can I solve that the whole "opening" animation going to be like opening a brochure, like here the first distribution opening. Sorry if you still don't get it I probably can't explain better than this.

Comment: you want it to appear to open like a book? When you hover over it, or some other time?

Comment: Yes exactly, when you hover over it just open a bit, and when you click on it it's open itself.

Comment: have you seen an example of something like it already existing? Can you post a link?

Comment: I only seen on video but if it's good for you I can attach it I gues.

Comment: I was just wondering if the effect was actually achieved with CSS/Script, or whether they used Canvas or Flash or something. Does the video mention the technology used?

Comment: No it's only a video about the advertisement and how it's look like, nothing more.

If you remember, the HBO's Taboo advertisement looks like the same.

Comment: I'm not from the US so don't see HBO unfortunately. And I tend to skip adverts in any case! I've posted something I think is an improvement.

Comment: Yea it's looks more like that. Thanks the help by the way. I'm doesn't live in the USA either, but it was an international advertisement, but I'm get your point. I'm still will looks after solution but that time I accept your answer like a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version makes it open more like a book:

```css
.cards {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.card-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 900;
  margin: auto auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card:hover .face {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.front {
  /*-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);*/
  z-index: auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.inner-left {
  /*-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);*/
  z-index: 2;
}

.inner-left>img {
  /*-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);*/
}

.inner-right {
  /*-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);*/
  z-index: 1;
}

.card:hover .front,
.card:hover .inner-left {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-toggle:checked+.card .front,
.card-toggle:checked+.card .inner-left {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-toggle:checked+.card .inner-right {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='cards'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="card-toggle" class="card-toggle" value="selected">
  <label class='card' for="card-toggle">
      <div class='front face'>
       Front view of the advertisement.
      </div>
    
      <div class="inner-left face">
       <img class="inner-left" width=300px height="600px" src='http://picanimal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cats-cat-play-hide-cute-pictures-hd-1366x768.jpg' />
      </div>
    
      <div class="inner-right face">
       <img class="inner-left" width=300px height="600px" src='http://picanimal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cats-cat-play-hide-cute-pictures-hd-1366x768.jpg' />
      </div>
     </label>
</div>
```